# Creating a Javascript API for a GWT application

Tags: javascript, api, gwt

All the GWT examples/tutorials talk about GWT client-side code being activated by events such as onPageLoad(). I want to use GWT to create a library that can be invoked by user-written Javascript function calls. Can anyone point me to the information needed to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) will almost definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to call any GWT code it must be initialized, and I would leave that up the GWT standard procedure for that.

[Here's how to call GWT methods from outside of GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling)

Answer (score 0):

The Dzone [refcard #1](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/gwt-style-configuration-and-js) has also a nice quick reference for JSNI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contributions.

gwt-exporter looks useful in theory, but so far I've failed to get it to work - it seems to be a fine piece of software ruined by poor documentation.

But I think I can probably do what I need using JSNI "by hand", now I'm starting to understand the architecture better.